# Generic Type array lint warning Array<>

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript

Getting following lint error

```
Array type using 'Array<T>' is forbidden. Use 'T[]' instead.
Replace generic-typed Array with array literal: Array<string>
```

And here is Array

```
interface INewsTitleType {
    id: string;
    item: {
        title: string;
    };
}
const newsTitleData: INewsTitleType[] = JSON.parse(news.newsSource.value);
const newsArray = newsTitleData as INewsTitleType[];
const savedtitle: Array<string> = [];
```

How to resolve this warning, I tried other ways too but still warning exists.

Comment: did you tried `const savedtitle: string[] = [];`

Comment: Yes, but it didn't work.

Comment: Why are you defining an empty array as a const? Normally you'd be wanting to do something with it. If you really intended that, why not try `const savedtitle = [];`

Comment: Maybe you are using `tslint` in your project with `array-type` rule define to `array` (https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/array-type/)

Comment: @JGFMK empty constant array is perfectly fine sincie const don't make constant array but only constant reference to array. Const is only so you can't reassign the value.

Comment: Maybe problem is your second array, it look kind of weird.

Comment: @joublic I realise the purpose of const to define an array that can't be modified. But if you want to compare an array to an empty array - you don't need a const to do that. I can't see any other reason for declaring savedtitle other than comparison.